# How to creating custom QR code reader?

Tags: android, qr-code

I know zing is the most famous QR code reader and very easy I can add and use it into my application. But i need something different.

The story is:
This QR code should be sensitive to just 20 (predefined) QR code.
When user clicks on a button QR code reader becomes active. If the QR code was one those 20, then in the middle of screen (while camera is still on) I have to put a dialog with an image and two button.
Because camera is still on, if user moves the camera to capture another QR code, the dialog with its content should change accordingly.

I have no idea how its possible. if you have any suggestion please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So I guess you should stay using xzing as the way to go. I do not mean to have xzing installed as Android App sending intents to it, but to take the source and let it do its work. After decoding the QR check resulting String if it was in your list of 20. If it is, show your dialog, if not just ignore that result. Scan multible QR's with Xzings build-in "Bulk-scan" mode.